# Mysql query and odd results

Tags: query, mysql, wpdb

I've a query here :

```
$sql = "SELECT ID,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_type 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE post_content LIKE {$stuff} 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = '{$post_type}' 
AND ID != {$post->ID} 
LIMIT {$limit}";
$results= $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

`$stuff` is a `%keyword%` and `$post_type` is a post type slug, the odd thing here is that when I use e.g. `articles` as post type, results also contains posts with `revision` status and `page` or `post` type and it seems that `if statements` like `post_type = '{$post_type}'` and `post_status = 'publish'` doesn't work at all!!

What should i do?

***Update***

I did a `print_r()` for `$sql` :

`SELECT ID,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_type FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%Battery%' OR post_content LIKE '%Watcher%' OR post_content LIKE '%Widget%' OR post_content LIKE '%matches%' OR post_content LIKE '%built%' OR post_content LIKE '%HTC%' OR post_content LIKE '%widgets%' OR post_content LIKE '%Please%' OR post_content LIKE '%check%' OR post_content LIKE '%Thrutu%' OR post_content LIKE '%day%' OR post_content LIKE '%job%' OR post_content LIKE '%app%' OR post_content LIKE '%donate%' OR post_content LIKE '%buying%' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'articles' AND ID != 1388 LIMIT 4`

Comment: What is a `%keyword%`? Also, `var_dump` your `$sql` and verify that all of the parameters are being set correctly?

Comment: That, and also you need to have single quotes around the stuff.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Please see the update

Comment: @Otto $sql contains it, please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose the OR part to brackets:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_type 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE (post_content LIKE {$stuff}) 
AND post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = '{$post_type}' 
AND ID != {$post->ID} 
LIMIT {$limit}";
$results= $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Try this one:

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_type FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_content LIKE '%Battery%' OR post_content LIKE '%Watcher%' OR post_content LIKE '%Widget%' OR post_content LIKE '%matches%' OR post_content LIKE '%built%' OR post_content LIKE '%HTC%' OR post_content LIKE '%widgets%' OR post_content LIKE '%Please%' OR post_content LIKE '%check%' OR post_content LIKE '%Thrutu%' OR post_content LIKE '%day%' OR post_content LIKE '%job%' OR post_content LIKE '%app%' OR post_content LIKE '%donate%' OR post_content LIKE '%buying%') AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'articles' AND ID != 1388 LIMIT 4
```